# how to pass random arguments to another python program in python script?

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am just trying to pass random arguments for below python script.

Code:

```
import json,sys,os,subprocess

arg1 = 'Site1'
arg2 = "443"
arg3 = 'admin@example.com'
arg4 = 'example@123'
arg5 = '--output req.txt'
arg6 = '-h'

obj=json.load(sys.stdin)

for i in range(len(obj['data'])):
    print obj['data'][i]['value']
    subprocess.call(['./malopinfo.py', arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, obj , arg5])
```

In above code variable `obj` will change randomly, But apart from that all arguments are static.

Error:

```
root@prabhu:/home/teja/MalopInfo/version1/MalopInfo# ./crver1.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   116    0   116    0     0   5313      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5523
11.945403842773683082
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qjson.py", line 15, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['./malopinfo.py', arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, obj])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
```

I am trying to execute is

```
python malopinfo.py Site1 443 admin@example.com example@123 11.945403842773683082 --output req.txt
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: The `sys.stdin` looks very suspicious. Are you sure that's the right command?

Comment: Yeah i can able to print my values using variable `obj`. If you see in error i can able to print value `11.945403842773683082`

Comment: `arg5` is `-h`, not `--output req.txt`!

Comment: @TejaR, did you notice that you declare arg5 twice? Run `' '.join(['./malopinfo.py', arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, obj , arg5])` to see if your program is called with correct arguments.

Comment: Sorry, Its Typo!! instead of `arg6` i typed `agr5`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're passing the entire `obj` dictionary into the command. To get the desired invocation, pass `obj['data'][i]['value']` in the arguments list to `subprocess.call`. So, the final line of your script should be

```
    subprocess.call(['./malopinfo.py', arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, obj['data'][i]['value'], arg5])
```

Or, you can make a variable to contain that on each loop iteration, whatever works.

Answer (score 1):

You are directly passing an object. Beforehand you need to convert that into string as `subprocess.call` will expect obj to be a string. Get the string value of one of the obj properties like you already have done `obj['data'][i]['value']` and pass it into your `subprocess.call`.